# How to automate password entry without user interference?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, sudo, password, su

How to type password automatically without user interference? For example

```
echo 'MyPassword@2014' > su UserName
```

I want to automate this in my script. The script should not wait for input. It should read from variable or file and proceed with further execution.

I know we have *`Expect`* tool for the same. But I want this to implement without *`Expect`* tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is **VERY INSECURE**! Use for your own risk.

`su` does not have such option but `sudo` does:

> **`-S, --stdin`**  Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

---

Example:

```
echo password | sudo -kS ./script
```